# C# COM server events “lost” when raising events while Excel is in edit mode

Tags: c#, excel, com, vba

I have an in-proc COM server written in C# (using .NET Framework 3.5) that raises COM events based on this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.90).aspx

Excel VBA is the most common client of my COM server.  I’ve found that when I raise COM events while Excel is in edit mode (e.g. a cell is being edited) the event is “lost”.  Meaning, the VBA event handler is never called (even after the Excel edit mode is finished) and the call to the C# event delegate passes through and fails silently with no exceptions being thrown.  Does anyone know how I can detect this situation on my COM server?  Or better still make the event delegate call block until Excel is out of edit mode?

I have tried:

- Inspecting the properties of the event delegate – could not find any property to indicate that the event failed to be raised on the client.
- Calling the event delegate directly from a worker thread and from the main thread – event not raised on the client, no exceptions thrown on the server.
- Pushing the event delegate onto a worker thread’s [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher(v=vs.90).aspx) and invoking it synchronously – event not raised on the client, no exceptions thrown on the server.
- Pushing the event delegate onto the main thread’s Dispatcher and invoking it synchronously and asynchronously – event not raised on the client, no exceptions thrown on the server.
- Checking the status code of the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call (using DispatcherOperation.Status) – the status is always ends with “Completed”, and is never in “Aborted” state.
- Creating an out-of-proc C# COM server exe and tested raising the events from there – same result, event handler never called, no exceptions.

Since I get no indication that the event was not raised on the client, I cannot handle this situation in my code.

Here is a simple test case.  The C# COM server:

```
namespace ComServerTest
{
    public delegate void EventOneDelegate();

    // Interface
    [Guid("2B2C1A74-248D-48B0-ACB0-3EE94223BDD3"), Description("ManagerClass interface")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IManagerClass
    {
        [DispId(1), Description("Describes MethodAAA")]
        String MethodAAA(String strValue);

        [DispId(2), Description("Start thread work")]
        String StartThreadWork(String strIn);

        [DispId(3), Description("Stop thread work")]
        String StopThreadWork(String strIn);
    }

    [Guid("596AEB63-33C1-4CFD-8C9F-5BEF17D4C7AC"), Description("Manager events interface")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ManagerEvents
    {
        [DispId(1), Description("Event one")]
        void EventOne();
    }

    [Guid("4D0A42CB-A950-4422-A8F0-3A714EBA3EC7"), Description("ManagerClass implementation")]
    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ManagerEvents))]
    public class ManagerClass : IManagerClass
    {
        private event EventOneDelegate EventOne;

        private System.Threading.Thread m_workerThread;
        private bool m_doWork;
        private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher MainThreadDispatcher = null;

        public ManagerClass()
        {
            // Assumes this is created on the main thread
            MainThreadDispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            m_doWork = false;
            m_workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoThreadWork);
        }

        // Simple thread that raises an event every few seconds
        private void DoThreadWork()
        {
            DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan fiveSecs = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            while (m_doWork)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - dtStart) > fiveSecs)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Raising event...");
                    try
                    {
                        if (EventOne != null)
                        {
                            // Tried calling the event delegate directly
                            EventOne();

                            // Tried synchronously invoking the event delegate from the main thread's dispatcher
                            MainThreadDispatcher.Invoke(EventOne, new object[] { });

                            // Tried asynchronously invoking the event delegate from the main thread's dispatcher
                            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation dispOp = MainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke(EventOne, new object[] { });

                            // Tried synchronously invoking the event delegate from the worker thread's dispatcher.
                            // Asynchronously invoking the event delegate from the worker thread's dispatcher did not work regardless of whether Excel is in edit mode or not.
                            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(EventOne, new object[] { });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        // No exceptions were thrown when attempting to raise the event when Excel is in edit mode
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                    }

                    dtStart = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

        // Method should be called from the main thread
        [ComVisible(true), Description("Implements MethodAAA")]
        public String MethodAAA(String strValue)
        {
            if (EventOne != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Tried calling the event delegate directly
                    EventOne();

                    // Tried asynchronously invoking the event delegate from the main thread's dispatcher
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation dispOp = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(EventOne, new object[] { });

                    // Tried synchronously invoking the event delegate from the main thread's dispatcher
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(EventOne, new object[] { });
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    // No exceptions were thrown when attempting to raise the event when Excel is in edit mode
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                }
                return "";
            }

            return "";
        }

        [ComVisible(true), Description("Start thread work")]
        public String StartThreadWork(String strIn)
        {
            m_doWork = true;
            m_workerThread.Start();
            return "";
        }

        [ComVisible(true), Description("Stop thread work")]
        public String StopThreadWork(String strIn)
        {
            m_doWork = false;
            m_workerThread.Join();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I register it using regasm:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm /codebase ComServerTest.dll /tlb:ComServerTest.tlb
```

Excel VBA client code:

```
Public WithEvents managerObj As ComServerTest.ManagerClass
Public g_nCounter As Long

Sub TestEventsFromWorkerThread()
    Set managerObj = New ComServerTest.ManagerClass

    Dim dtStart As Date
    dtStart = DateTime.Now

    g_nCounter = 0

    Debug.Print "Start"

    ' Starts the worker thread which will raise the EventOne event every few seconds
    managerObj.StartThreadWork ""

    Do While True
        DoEvents

        ' Loop for 20 secs
        If ((DateTime.Now - dtStart) * 24 * 60 * 60) > 20 Then
            ' Stops the worker thread
            managerObj.StopThreadWork ""
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub

Sub TestEventFromMainThread()
    Set managerObj = New ComServerTest.ManagerClass

    Debug.Print "Start"

    ' This call will raise the EventOne event
    managerObj.MethodAAA ""

    Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub

' EventOne handler
Private Sub managerObj_EventOne()
    Debug.Print "EventOne " & g_nCounter
    g_nCounter = g_nCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Edit 27/11/2014 - I've been doing some more investigation on this.

This problem *also* occurs for a C++ MFC Automation server that raises COM events.  If I raise the COM event from the main thread when Excel is in edit mode, the event handler is never called.  No errors or exceptions are thrown on the server, similar to my C# COM server.  **However**, if I use the Global Interface Table to marshal the event sink interface from the main thread *back* to the main thread, then invoking the event - it will block while Excel is in edit mode.  (I also used COleMessageFilter to disable the busy dialog and not responding dialogs, otherwise I'd receive the exception: *RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_INEXTERNALCALL It is illegal to call out while inside message filter.*)

(let me know if you'd like to see the MFC Automation code, I'm skipping it for brevity)

Knowing that, I tried to do the same on my C# COM server.  I could instantiate the Global Interface Table (using the definition from pinvoke.net) and the message filter (using the IOleMessageFilter definition from MSDN).  However, the event still gets "lost" and does not block while Excel is in edit mode.

Here's how I modified my C# COM server:

```
namespace ComServerTest
{
    // Global Interface Table definition from pinvoke.net
    [
        ComImport,
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
        Guid("00000146-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
    ]
    interface IGlobalInterfaceTable
    {
        uint RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pUnk,
                [In] ref Guid riid);

        void RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal(uint dwCookie);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object GetInterfaceFromGlobal(uint dwCookie, [In] ref Guid riid);
    }

    [
        ComImport,
        Guid("00000323-0000-0000-C000-000000000046") // CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable
    ]
    class StdGlobalInterfaceTable /* : IGlobalInterfaceTable */
    {
    }

    public class ManagerClass : IManagerClass
    {
        //...skipped code already mentioned in earlier sample above...
        //...also skipped the message filter code for brevity...
        private Guid IID_IDispatch = new Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
        private IGlobalInterfaceTable m_GIT = null;

        public ManagerClass()
        {
            //...skipped code already mentioned in earlier sample above...
            m_GIT = (IGlobalInterfaceTable)new StdGlobalInterfaceTable();
        }

        public void FireEventOne()
        {
            // Using the GIT to marshal the (event?) interface from the main thread back to the main thread (like the MFC Automation server).
            // Should we be marshalling the ManagerEvents interface pointer instead?  How do we get at it?
            uint uCookie = m_GIT.RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(this, ref IID_IDispatch);
            ManagerClass mgr = (ManagerClass)m_GIT.GetInterfaceFromGlobal(uCookie, ref IID_IDispatch);
            mgr.EventOne(); // when Excel is in edit mode, event handler is never called and does not block, event is "lost"
            m_GIT.RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal(uCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

I’d like my C# COM server to behave in a similar way to the MFC Automation server.  Is this possible?  I think I should be registering the ManagerEvents interface pointer in the GIT but I don't know how to get at it?  I tried using Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(ManagerEvents)) but that just throws an exception: *System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.*

Comment: In C# code, put a debug trace like `Debug.Print` inside `EventOne`. Do you see the trace after you've called `MainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke(EventOne, ...)`?

Comment: @Noseratio Sorry I don't understand. I can't put a debug trace inside `EventOne` because it is a delegate, and the method it references is in the VBA code (`managerObj_EventOne`).  Perhaps I'm not understanding you clearly, could you illustrate with some code?  Thanks.

Comment: I meant this: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Debug.Print("Hello!"); EventOne(); }), new object[] { });` Do you see "Hello!" in the debug output this way?

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for clarifying.  Yes, I do see "Hello!" printed in the debug output, but the VBA event handler doesn't get called when editing a cell in Excel.

Comment: In Excel, put a `MessageBox 'Hello from VBA'` instead of `Do While True: DoEvents ... `. Try it along with `MainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke` on the managed side. Does the VBA event handler get called when the message box is on?

Comment: @Noseratio When the message box is on, the VBA event handler does not get called.  The dispatcher is executing the delegate though, as I still see "Hello!" being printed in the debug output.

Comment: Now I'd assume VBA event handlers are not hooked up while Excel is in edit mode, but I don't have a good explanation for why your out-of-proc server is blocking until Excel is out of edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a callback method instead of Event

1- Change the interface:

```
// Interface
[Guid("2B2C1A74-248D-48B0-ACB0-3EE94223BDD3"), Description("ManagerClass interface")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IManagerClass
{
    [DispId(1), Description("Describes MethodAAA")]
    String MethodAAA(String strValue);

    [DispId(2), Description("Start thread work")]
    String StartThreadWork(String strIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ref Action callback);

    [DispId(3), Description("Stop thread work")]
    String StopThreadWork(String strIn);
}
```

2- Add a field to hold the callback method and change the caller method:

```
    [ComVisible(false)]
    Action callBack;

    // Simple thread that raises an event every few seconds
    private void DoThreadWork()
    {
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan fiveSecs = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        while (m_doWork)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - dtStart) > fiveSecs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Raising event...");
                try
                {
                    if (callBack != null)
                        callBack();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    // No exceptions were thrown when attempting to raise the event when Excel is in edit mode
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                }

                dtStart = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true), Description("Start thread work")]
    public String StartThreadWork(String strIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ref Action callback)
    {
        this.callBack = callback;
        m_doWork = true;
        m_workerThread.Start();
        return "";
    }
```

3- Add a module to your VBA (because AddressOf will work only on module SUBs) and place this method inside that module

```
Dim g_nCounter As Integer

Public Sub callback()
    Debug.Print "EventOne " & g_nCounter
    g_nCounter = g_nCounter + 1
End Sub
```

4- Pass the address of this newly created SUB to your managed method:

```
managerObj.StartThreadWork "", AddressOf Module1.callback
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, the callback does indeed get called when Excel is in edit mode.  It's a good workaround, however I'm not sure if I can accept it as the answer, because while I do know that my clients are familiar with VBA events, I don't know if they are familiar with registering callback functions using AddressOf.  Upvoted.

Comment: The bad news is that for an unknown reason (if there has been any REASON ever) the events are 'cut' somewhere between the managed code and VBA interpreter. I found out about this after a lot of native debugging and didn't found anything but the fact that excel disables the developer tools as well as the VBA editor when editing a cell.

Comment: I'm still thinking about that native server you made which was working